# Redux combineReducers, with child properties at same level as child reducers

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I would like to have this shape of data:

```
let shop = Map({
  shopInput: '',
  shopShouldHideResults: true,
  place: null,
  position: {},
  shopAutocompleteResults: {
    predictions: [{ description: '' }]
  }
})

let product = Map({
  brand: '',
  name: '',
  description: '',
  image: null,
  price: null,
  id: null,
  item: 'MEAL'
})

export const addPage: Map<*, *> = Map({
  shop: shop,
  product: product,  
  shopListDisplayed: false,
  rerenderKey: false
})
```

So `addPage` has a product reducer and a shop reducer and its own reducer just for its own two properties "shopListDisplayed" and "rerenderKey"

My reducers:

```
export const addPage = (
  state: Map<*, *> = applicationState.get('addPage'),
  action: AddPageAction
): Map<*, *> => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SHOP_LIST_DISPLAYED: {
      return state.set('shopListDisplayed', (action.payload: boolean))
    }
    case UPDATE_RERENDER_KEY: {
      return state.set('rerenderKey', (!state.get('rerenderKey'): boolean))
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const product = (
  state: Map<*, *> = applicationState
    .get('addPage').get('product'),
  action: AddPageAction
): Map<*, *> => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_BRAND: {
      return state.set('brand', (action.payload: string))
    }
    case UPDATE_NAME: {
      return state.set('name', (action.payload: string))
    }
    case UPDATE_ITEM_TYPE: {
      return state.set('item', (action.payload: string))
    }
    case UPDATE_DESCRIPTION: {
      return state.set('description', (action.payload: string))
    }
    case UPDATE_PRODUCT_ID: {
      return state.set('id', (action.payload: number))
    }
    case UPDATE_PRICE: {
      return state.set('price', (action.payload: number))
    }
    case UPDATE_IMAGE: {
      return state.set('image', (action.payload: Image | any))
    }
    case UPDATE_IMAGE_LINK: {
      return state.set('imageLink', (action.payload: string))
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const shop = (
  state: Map<*, *> = applicationState.get('addPage').get('shop'),
  action: Object
): any => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SHOP_INPUT: {
      return state.set('shopInput', action.payload.shopInput)
    }
    case UPDATE_SHOP_PLACE: {
      return state.set('place', action.payload.place)
    }
    case UPDATE_SHOP_SHOULD_HIDE_RESULTS: {
      return state.set('shopShouldHideResults', action.payload)
    }
    case GET_SHOP_AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_REJECTED: {
      console.log(
        'there was an issue getting your autocomplete results: ',
        action.payload
      )
      return state
    }
    case GET_SHOP_AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULTS_FULFILLED: {
      return state.set('shopAutocompleteResults', action.payload)
    }
    case GET_SHOP_PLACE_DETAILS_FULFILLED: {
      return state.set('place', action.payload.result)
    }
    case GET_SHOP_PLACE_DETAILS_REJECTED: {
      console.log('there was an issue getting place details: ', action.payload)
      return state
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

How do I use `combineReducers` in this case?

Currently I have:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  addPage: combineReducers({shop, product}),
  alertModal,
  categories,
  distanceSlider,
  editProduct,
  map,
  menu,
  searchPage: combineReducers({location}),
  searchPageFields: searchPageFields,
  searchResults,
  searchResultsPresenter
```

I don't think my `combineReducers` takes into account `shopListDisplayed: false,rerenderKey: false`. I have not explicitely added in `addPage` reducer into `combineReducers` which deals with those two root properties of the `addPage`.

Where do I put that into `combineReducers`?

I get this error:

> Unexpected properties "shopListDisplayed", "rerenderKey" found in the
>   previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the
>   known reducer property names instead: "shop", "product". Unexpected
>   properties will be ignored.